# JSON OpenWeatherMap API data into a String

Tags: json, rest, api, jersey

I want to output a string onto the screen saying something like `"Dublin is experiencing clouds today with a temperature of 15".`

How do I target weather.main and temperature from this JSON and put it into my string?

Here is my code for targeting the api and returning the JSON. I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated!

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/weather")
public class Weather {


@GET
@Path("/{param}")
    public Response GetCityInfo(@PathParam("param") String city) {

    String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&mode=JSON&APPID=cbb5da68f37d26059628449e068ce931";
    Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Response r = c.target(URL).request().get();
    return r;
    }

}
```

Using Postman with the url http://localhost:49000/api/weather/dublin it returns:

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": -6.26,
    "lat": 53.35
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 803,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "broken clouds",
        "icon": "04d"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 287.71,
    "pressure": 1009,
    "humidity": 82,
    "temp_min": 287.15,
    "temp_max": 288.15
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
    "speed": 6.7,
    "deg": 220
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 75
},
"dt": 1539694800,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5237,
    "message": 0.0019,
    "country": "IE",
    "sunrise": 1539672865,
    "sunset": 1539710737
},
"id": 2964574,
"name": "Dublin",
"cod": 200
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is the same `Response` class, there are actually two different subtypes which are for two totally different cases. When you are getting a `Response` back from a `Client` you are getting an *inbound* response. You cannot return an inbound `Response` from a resource method. You must return an *outbound* `Response`. You create it by using one of the static methods. See the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html). For example, you can do

```
 return Response.ok(entity).build();
```

That creates an outbound response. From the inbound response, you need to extract the data. You do that with `Response#readEntity(Class)`. So what you could do is something like

```
 Response r = c.target(URL).request().get();
 String data = r.readEntity(String.class);
 return Response.ok(data).build();
```